# Error getting the rendered property for a table in Oracle ADF Faces

Tags: java, oracle, jsf, oracle-adf

I'm trying to render/not render a table during the preRender Fase. I'm using jDev 10.3.1.4

I set up a table with the "rendered" attribute set like this:

```
<af:table binding="#{backingBean.table1}" banding="row"
                rendered="#{backingBean.table1.rendered}">
```

In the backing bean i did

```
protected void onPagePreRender(PagePhaseEvent event) {
     getTable1().setRendered(false);
     AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(getTable1());
}
```

And i keep getting the error `Error getting property 'rendered' from bean of type oracle.adf.view.faces.component.core.data.CoreTable`

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `rendered` attribute. It's basically referencing itself in an infinite loop. You don't need it if you already programmatically manipulate it by the component referenced by `binding`.

If you really intend to use the `rendered` attribute, the proper usage would be:

```
<af:table binding="#{backingBean.table1}" banding="row"
    rendered="#{backingBean.rendered}">
```

with

```
private boolean rendered = true;

protected void onPagePreRender(PagePhaseEvent event) {
    rendered = false;
    AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(getTable1());
}

public boolean isRendered() {
    return rendered;
}
```